# Macro is not working with Visual Studio 2017

Tags: mfc, macros, visual-studio-2017

I am trying to use the **Visual Studio 2017 RC** and am encountering a problem.

I appreciate that it is only *release candidate*.

In my 2015 project I have a macro:

```
#define SMLABEL(a) GetSMLabel(a, #a)
```

Here is the associated method:

```
CString CChristianLifeMinistryEditorDlg::GetSMLabel(UINT uID, CString strLabel)
{
    CString strText;

    if (theApp.UseTranslationINI())
        strText = theApp.GetSMLabel(strLabel);
    else
        strText.LoadString(uID);

    return strText;
}
```

Here is an example of using the macro:

```
strDate.FormatMessage(SMLABEL(IDS_STR_TPL_OCLM_WEEK),
    theApp.CustomFormatDate(datThisMonday, _T("%B")), datThisMonday.GetDay(), datEndOfWeek.GetDay());
```

In VS2015 it compiles and works no problem.

But using the new compiler I get these build errors:

> 1>ChristianLifeMinistryEditorDlg.cpp(471): error C2664: 'CString
>   CChristianLifeMinistryEditorDlg::GetSMLabel(UINT,CString)': cannot
>   convert argument 2 from 'const char [22]' to 'CString'
>   1>ChristianLifeMinistryEditorDlg.cpp(471): note: Constructor for class
>   'ATL::CStringT>>'
>   is declared 'explicit'

Clearly there is an issue with the second parameter but I don't know how to redefine the macro declaration.

Update:

I have tried changing my `GetSMLabel` method to have a second parameter of `LPTSTR` or `TCHAR*` but it will not compile.

I understand that when in my macro I use the # it converts it to a string literal. And the new compiler does not like this.

Also tried changing the macro:

```
#define SMLABEL(a) GetSMLabel(a, CString(#a))
```

Still won't work.

Comment: Assuming that your project is set to use Unicode, this appears to be a breaking change in that the [conversion c'tors](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5bzxfsea.aspx#cstringt__cstringt) of `CStringT` are now marked explicit by default. If that is the case, you have two options: Change the macro to use an explicit constructor call (for the second parameter), or have the macro produce a wide character string. The latter is recommended, although I'm not sure that you can replace `#a` with `_T(#a)`. This may need an extra indirection.

Comment: I confess that I don't strictly understand what *explicit* means nor the implication. But your suggestion about using `_T(#a)` worked. Phew! It just leaves one final compile error now. I will ask if I get stuck (it is assigning a `CString` variable from a `const char *` variable. `CString strWeek = pWeek->Name();` Would this be separate question? Under the hood I think it is a related issue.

Comment: The root cause is probably related, but the solution is a different one (or maybe not). If at all possible, change `pWeek->Name()` to return a wide character string. If that is not possible or feasible, you need an explicit constructor invocation. I believe `CString strWeek{ pWeek->Name() };` should work.